# How to fix fragments backstack issues in android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

Hi everyone i have an issue in my code , i am using one main activity and two fragments (mainfragment,mainsubfragment) the application is about getting data from json parser and displaying it in mainfragment and when you click on it , it should display some data in mainsubfragment.The problem is that when i click on one of the display item in mainfragment its replace this fragment with mainsubfragment with key upon which it should get some more data from another json parser but instead it shows nothing and when i pressed back to mainfragment nothing display there as well.A quick help will be appreciated...

Comment: there is definitely some error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a singleton named NavigationHandler and add the below functions to it:

Function to open MainFragment:

```
public void openMainFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, MainFragment fragment){
        String backStackName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fl_main_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(backStackName)
                .commit();
    }
```

Function to open SubFragment:

```
public void openSubFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager, SubFragment fragment){
        String backStackName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStackName, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fl_main_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(backStackName)
                .commit();
    }
```

For backpress:

```
public void navigateBackBy(AppCompatActivity activity, int numOfFragments){
        if(mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()==1){
            activity.finish();
        }
        else {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < numOfFragments; i++) {
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
            }
        }
    }
```

In your Activity:

1. Call openMainFragment(...) to open the MainFragment with the list.
2. While calling your adapter constructor pass FragmentManager as a parameter.
3. Override onBackPressed() & add call navigateBackBy(this, 1);. This method is useful to go back by any no. of fragments.

Inside your adapter:

1. On click of an item call openSubFragment(...).

Comment: For your 2nd issue, where nothing is being displayed in your SubFragment, first check if you are getting any data in the JSON response and if you have data after parsing JSON.

Comment: Many thanks Aishwarya Tiwari for your reply i am going to try the code the way you mention ...

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Do one thing. Add different background colors to the main & subfragment then run it. It is an easy debug to find what view/ layout is being displayed.

Comment: You were right i changed the color of both fragments (MainFragment with blue color and MainSubFragment with pink color)  MainFragment display but when i clicked on one of his item  ,only white screen got display thats it...

Comment: Remove this line from openSubFragment(...) & tell me the output- fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(backStackName, POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: Aishwarya Tiwari i need to ask you one more thing that how to get json parser from online website using genymotion....?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: In my current app i am getting data from json parser using localhost , what about getting data from online website  and not from localhost ?

Comment: To get data you need to make HTTP calls to your server, where you send request & server gives you JSON data in response. Use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)  to achieve that.

Comment: I am using that inside asyntask : OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://10.0.3.2/Cargo/mydbcon.php?id="+integers[0])
                        .build();

Comment: its work fine in localhost ,but i want to get data from my online website e.g ...url("mywebsite.com/mydbcon.php?id="+integers[0]).build();

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this.

Comment: Thanks anyway for help , Aishwarya tiwari do you have any blog that i can follow you in ....Incase if i need some help .

Comment: No nothing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack over flow 
According to you , you are using two fragment 
1.mainfragment >> don't add to addToBackStack
2.mainsubfragment>>  add to addToBackStack

for fragmetn1 call like as

```
   Fragment  fragment = new mainfragment();
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

for second fragment2

```
        fragment = new mainsubfragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

then it will be work and on back press also will be work

Comment: Thanks Binesh kumar for quick reply ,Basically i am replacing fragments from adapter class .

Comment: Why you are calling from adapter